# Can't Install any app from Chrome web store

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

I've been trying to install the Arc Welder app from Chrome web store. But an error arises whenever I press the Add button saying " NETWORK_FAILED". What may be the problem ?

Comment: Any app or just that app? What about on a different chrome account? Have you restarted the computer/chrome?

Comment: @Raystafarian Every app that I tried to install, failed. I've also restarted computer/chrome.

Comment: do you have any other installed apps/

Comment: @Sachith Nothing other than the default Google apps

Comment: can you access web sites?